# Enabling Virtual network access from Azure API management service

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I have backend API service running in my Azure VNET and thus wants to configure API management service to have access to internal VNET subnet. When going to API management service >> Virtual network >> Internal >> Select your VNET and subnet >>> Save.

The below error is what is shown.

> Authentication Failed : AADSTS700027: Client assertion contains an
>   invalid signature. [Reason - The key was not found., Thumbprint of key
>   used by client: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX', Please visit
>   'https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer' and query
>   for
>   'https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
>   to see configured keys] Trace ID:
>   XXXXXXXXXXX_XXXXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXxx Correlation ID:
>   XXXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXx-XXXXXXXXXX

Comment: Do you have full access to the virtual network / subnet resources or might it be limited?

Answer (score 0):

Just check if you have encountered any issues in **[Common Network Configuration Issues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-using-with-vnet#-common-network-configuration-issues)**